# Binding ASP.NET TreeView Control to a Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) they say about TreeView control ("Binding to Data" paragraph):

> The TreeView control can also be bound to an XmlDocument object **or a
> DataSet object with relations**. To bind to one of these data sources,
> set the DataSource property of the TreeView control to the data
> source, and then call the DataBind method.

So in a simple WebForms page with only a TreeView i wrote:

```
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("Masters");
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
     dt.Columns.Add("MasterId", typeof(Int32));
     dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
     DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Details");
     ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
     dt1.Columns.Add("DetailId", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("MasterId", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

     DataRow rw;
     DataRow rw1;
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
        rw=dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        rw["MasterId"] = i;
        rw["Name"] = "Master Name " + i.ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
           rw1 = dt1.NewRow();
           dt1.Rows.Add(rw1);
           rw1["DetailId"] = i * 5 + j;
           rw1["MasterId"] = i;
           rw1["Name"] = "Detail Name " + j.ToString() + " of Master Name "+ i.ToString();
        }
     }
     ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("Masters_Details",dt.Columns["MasterId"], dt1.Columns["MasterId"]));
     TreeView1.DataSource = ds;
     TreeView1.DataBind();
```

But in line where i set DataSource it throws exception:

**HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.**

I understood this occurs because DataSet doesn't implement such interface ... so why did they write is possible to bind to a "DataSet with relations"?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25753/Binding-the-ASP-NET-TreeView-to-a-DataSet-or-an-Ob  Although, it doesn't explain the language in the documentation.

Comment: tks i read that article....and a lot of them where TreeView has populated node by node...but the key point of my question is **why** they say is possible in a native way.

Comment: In such a case on MSDN, I usually rate the topic unhelpful and then give an explanation of my reasoning or what should be there instead.  ie: where's the example for that case, what's the closest you can come up with.

Comment: I am not sure why they write it that way, but it's really not possible to bind the dataset with relations that way since dataset is not implementing IHierarchicalDataSource  or IHierarchicalEnumerable. 

Unless you could bypass the checking:
System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ValidateDataSource(Object dataSource) which I don't think possible by using out of the box functionalities.

Answer (score -1):

This code shows how to go from a hierarchical table to a TreeView. There is nothing sophisticated here, but a few tricks are needed to make it work.

The first trick is to sort the records by the ParentID. We cannot insert a node into the tree until its parent node is in the tree. This implies a special case where the root node of the tree must be inserted first since it has no parent.

**Here is sample data:**

```
// Create the DataTable and columns
DataTable ItemTable = new DataTable("MyTable");
ItemTable.Columns.Add("ID"      , typeof(int   ));
ItemTable.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int   ));
ItemTable.Columns.Add("Name"    , typeof(String));

// add some test data
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0,-1, "Bill Gates"    });
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 0, "Steve Ballmer" });
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1, "Mary Smith"    });
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 0, "Paul Allen"    });
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2, "Ahmed Jones"   });
ItemTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2, "Wing Lee"      });

// Use the Select method to sort the rows by ParentID
DataRow[] SortedRows;
SortedRows = ItemTable.Select("", "ParentID");
```

I hope you find this useful,

Comment: Thank you for you interest to my question, but what you wrote is for populate TreeView node by node a little different from use binding feature.

Comment: But in your code you were getting below error HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.

Comment: Yes, but in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) they wrote is possible to bind to a Dataset... why did they write this ?